# PHP multiple fields search with multiple operators

Tags: php, search

I am looking best solution in PHP for a search form which has multiple fields and person can also choose operation on that field. Here is how it will work for example. Also allow me to set what operations are possible on field without hard-coding. There will be many fields on page i am explaining on few on them.

### Scenario examples :

- Lets field "age" there can be three scenario. age can be greater than
  or equal to or less than given field. So on page for a field person
  will be able to select operation type from drop-down
  "equal,greater,lesser" and then specify value.
- Similarly for subject it can have following scenarios. subject equals
  selected, or in multiple selected subjects, or not in selected
  subjects.

I don't wanna hard-code solution for each field, i want something that's more flexible with which i can add or remove fields later without changing major part of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve it with collaborated code between PHP and Javascript. Created array in PHP with name of field, then what type of operations it support and other optined needed.

Then in jQuery hide display and restrict field options based on options that i output from PHP array.